# Dealing with trailing newline when checking for palindromes

Tags: python, palindrome

I was trying to import a palindrome function from a previously made code. Initially the palindrome code was working properly, but after I imported it, it is not showing correct answer.

```
import re
def check(string):
    if (string==string[::-1]):
        print ("{} is palindorme".format(string))
    else:
        print ("{} is not palindorme".format(string))



def palindrome(text):
    c=re.sub('["?",",",".","/","@","#","%","&","*","!"," "]',"",text)
    check(c)
```

This is the function I am using:

```
from pal_func import palindrome
f=open("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\test file.txt",'r')
c=f.readline().lower()
print(c)
palindrome(c)
```

Output should be:

```
was it a cat i saw?
wasitacatisaw is palindrome
```

But it is showing:

```
was it a cat i saw?

wasitacatisaw

 is not palindorme
```

Comment: Could you format your code to be more readable? In the current state, it is a little confusing.

Comment: Can not reproduce, works fine for me. Are you importing from the correct file? what exactly is in the text file?

Comment: @Banana In the text file i have just 1 line: "Was it a cat I saw?". Yes i am importing from correct file.

Comment: @beninato......I hope corrected one is ok

Comment: @beninato....I hope so....This is my first time i am posting so i am not sure about format

Comment: @ChitranshMathur If what you just wrote is correct, then the error lies in capitalization. The palindrome check here is case sensitive, so if your sentence starts with a capital "W", it will show as no palindrome. You can use str.lower() to alleviate that.

Comment: @Banana......Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In brief

Strip the trailing newline with:

```
c=f.readline().lower().strip()
```

### In details

Your problem does not seem to come from the code, but from the way you read your file.

The function `readline` reads a line from the file but **will not strip the trailing newline**. The hint was that the answer

```
wasitacatisaw
 is not palindrom
```

has a newline you didn't write yourself

So the function check get the string `wasitacatisaw<newline>`, which is not a palindrom.

**Last word** : the next time, please also provide the file you're dealing with (without any personal infos nor passwords, of course), so that SO user can reproduce the error :)

Comment: Thank You It worked. From next time i will surely provide with the file.

Comment: It isn't yet :) to do so (if you want to, of course, but since you're new I'm showing you around) you can click on the checkmark under the answer score. 
see [an image here](https://images.app.goo.gl/k6oWNNoRuWjyqrQW6) and [the official doc](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). 

Both of us will win some reputation, and future users are more likely to search for an answer in this post